# TCS conferences for undergraduate students?

Tags: soft-question, conferences

I have noticed that ICFP has a student volunteer program and research program that accepts undergraduate students and POPL have the Programming Language Mentoring Workshop, so I was wondering if there are any other conferences with similar programs within TCS?

Also, would it be very likely that an undergraduate student would get any funding for these programs, as I am assuming the organisers would prefer postgraduate students? I would be very interested in attending the PLMW at POPL but as it's in India next year, it would be hard to self fund...

Edit: Thanks for the suggestions, I have checked some of them out, but I should have probably added that I am in the UK, so some of them would be quite far, but I know of a couple of similar undergraduate conferences to the ones mentioned by vzn so I will consider that route too...

Comment: You may want to consider the AMS-MAA Joint Mathematics Meetings, which are organized every year in January. They have undergrad research poster sessions, see e.g. the information from this year: http://www.maa.org/programs/students/undergraduate-research/jmm-poster-session. I think TCS research projects will be welcome. From briefly browsing this year's list, I saw quite a few posters with computational content, including work on quantum computing, machine learning and data mining, bioinformatics. Of course, this is way broader than a TCS conference, and covers all kinds of mathematics.

Answer (score 6):

The POPL-colocated PLMW, which you mentioned, certainly provides travel support for undergraduate as well as graduate students.  I personally know undergrads who've been supported. If you're interested in PL research (of any kind, not just POPL-like research) I encourage you to apply.

The ACM student research contest (of which the ICFP SRC is a part) includes categories for both undergraduates and graduates. For SRC at SIGPLAN affiliated conferences like ICFP or PLDI, you can apply to the [SIGPLAN PAC program](http://www.sigplan.org/PAC/Main) for travel support.

Comment: I'm an undergrad who is not planning to go to this (if the research group I'm in will fund it anyways)

Answer (score 3):

The best option might be the [FCRC](http://fcrc.acm.org/), which combines lots of famous and interesting theoretical conferences and others.  I didn't see the policy for supporting undergraduate students, but I believe they would waive your registration fee should you write to ask (maybe they need volunteers?).  Especially, as you mentioned POPL, PLDI suits a little more for undergraduate students.

Answer (score 3):

For the past three years, SOCG has included a satellite event called the Young Researchers Forum, which is a venue for early students and other newcomers to computational geometry to present preliminary or ongoing research. It's not meant specifically for undergraduates, but undergrads are certainly welcome.

Most major theory conferences have been able to attract funding from NSF to support student travel.  Again, undergraduates are eligible for this funding, although students speaking at the conference (including the Young Researchers Forum at SOCG) generally have higher priority.

Answer (score 1):

(alas) there is a basic mismatch between the two areas: undergraduate and research, because most serious research happens at least at the graduate level. however consider the following (which are not (T)CS focused but encompass it):

- [National Conference on Undergraduate Research](http://www.cur.org/ncur_2014/) / [2014 CS presentations](https://ncurdb.cur.org/ncur2014/search/List_NCUR.aspx?subject=Computer+Science) / [Final program pdf](http://www.cur.org/assets/1/7/Final_Program_small.pdf) has many undergraduate (T)CS research presentations.
- [Sigma Xi research conference](http://www.sigmaxi.org/meetings/src/src.shtml) includes undergraduate research in "all fields of science and engineering." ([2013 notes](http://www.sigmaxi.org/meetings/src/2013src.shtml))

try also Mathematics oriented conferences which would liberally allow computer science touching areas as a subdiscipline or overlap.

- [Young mathematicians conference](http://ymc.osu.edu/) Ohio State University
- [MAA RUMC program](http://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/undergraduate-conferences/supported-conferences). MAA [RUMC](http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-grants/undergraduateresearchresources) are Regional Undergraduate Mathematics Conferences.