# research papers for undergraduate students

Tags: reference-request

The papers presented at conferences like SODA, FOCS are hard to understand for undergraduates. Also a lot of background knowledge is assumed for understanding such papers. Are there any conferences/resources/websites where I can find interesting research paper readable by undergrads.

thanks

Comment: Research papers are typically written for experts in the area. Look for surveys and exposition papers and also books (specially handbooks), they typically are more readable in my experience.

Comment: some research papers are written by (advanced) undergrads. eg try [TCS conferences for undergraduates](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/24968/tcs-conferences-for-undergraduate-students). there is also a program in US sponsored by NSF called "Research Experiences for Undergraduates" where sometimes papers are written, although they are not centrally collected.

Comment: Not every paper in top conferences need a lot of background. Usually by reading abstract or introduction of paper you will get feeling whether you can follow it. If there are few things you don't know them, it's not bad to learn them.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that all science papers have to be very complicated and rough for undergraduates. When I was still really fresh in CS I found a lot of science papers that helped me understand many problems. Try to look for something interesting for you on http://paperity.org/. I found many interesting journals and papers. I think this is currently the most useful aggregator on web